# SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager

Tags: shutdown, services, sql-server, sql

I have an issue since I installed SQL Server 2016 on my PC. Randomly, SQL server stops and disables I need to re enable the service and start it manually. I've tried to set it up so that it restarts automatically with no luck.

This is the message I get:
Message
SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

then all this:
Service Broker manager has shut down.

.NET Framework runtime has been stopped.

SQL Server shutdown has been initiated

SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully deregistered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/AR5CG748278R.CSCMWS.CSCMWS.COM ] for the SQL Server service.

The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully deregistered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/AR5CG748278R.CSCMWS.CSCMWS.COM:1433 ] for the SQL Server service.

Any ideas why I'm getting all this? and how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi Matias.. I am facing the same issue. Were you able to figureout the solition?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling SQL server